# How do I rendering multiple js files in one ReactDom line in React(Target container is not a DOM element in React)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render two files in one window. I expect that when I run "npm start" it shoule be show login part and main part in one window. It works if I using one of them. For example, ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root')); or ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
and it shows each page. Also, when I wrote both of them, it shows the last one that is main. So, I tried to write both of them in the same line as ReactDOM.render(, , document.getElementById('root')); but I got "Target container is not a DOM element" this error message. What should I do if I want to get two files in one window?

I will leave my code below just in case.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Main from './pages/Main/Main';


ReactDOM.render(<Login />, <Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thank you for helping me out in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct you want to render files inside of index.js, you need to use this method:

import React from "react";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./index.css";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(

```
<React.StrictMode>

    <App />

</React.StrictMode>,

document.getElementById("root")
```

);